Bootstrap 5 mega menu disappears quickly
I have this Bootstrap 5 mega dropdown, I have an issue with it as it disappears quickly when I try to select the contents. I believe I have CSS affecting this but just can't figure it out.
I have tried increasing the transition time and increase the z-index value but to no avail. I can't figure what CSS property I need to add to enable the hover effect stay up.


.header {
  min-height: 70pt;
}

#alaid-header .logo h1 {
  font-size: 38px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#alaid-header .logo h1 a,
#alaid-header .logo h1 a:hover {
  color: #3c4133;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#alaid-header .logo img {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 78px;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar li {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #026a3f !important;
}

.navbar a,
.navbar a:focus {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 30px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar a i,
.navbar a:focus i {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.navbar .active,
.navbar .active:focus,
.navbar li:hover>a {
  color: #c57b0d !important;
}

.navbar a i {
  color: #c57b0d !important;
}


/* dropdown 2 */

.dropdown-menu {
  width: 980px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 15px);
  /* z-index: 99; */
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  /* background-color: #fff; */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 5s ease;
}

.dropdown-hover:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 250;
}

.dropdown-hover>.dropdown-toggle:active {
  /*Without this, clicking will make it sticky*/
  pointer-events: none;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
  font-size: 13px !important;
  margin-left: -29px;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 0.5rem 0xp;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<header id="alaid-header" class="d-flex align-items-center bg-white shadow header">
  <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div class="logo">
      <h1 class="text-light">
        <a href="index.php">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="w-100" />
        </a>
      </h1>
    </div>

    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar alaid-navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link active" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item  dropdown-hover position-static">
          <a data-mdb-dropdown-init class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-mdb-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Lorem ipsum<i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i>
        </a>
          <!-- Dropdown menu -->
          <div class="dropdown-menu w-100 mt-0" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-top-left-radius: 0;border-top-right-radius: 0;">
            <div class="container mx-0">
              <div class="row my-4">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 mb-3 mb-lg-0">
                  <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <h6><strong>Lorem3</strong></h6>
                    <hr />
                    <a href="">lorem ipsum eer</a>
                    <a href="">lorem ipsum</a>
                    <a href="">lorem emsm</a>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 mb-3 mb-lg-0">
                  <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <h6><strong>Dogs</strong></h6>
                    <hr />
                    <a href="">Caucaian</a>
                    <a href="">Bull</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




It is not totally clear to me what effect you're trying to achieve. Are you saying that when you select an item from the mega-dropdown-menu, what you call "contents", that you want the menu, and hover state, to stay as they are? For how long? What will any user think of that? How to know that anything was clicked?

This is a perfect example of including a working snippet along with your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@KIKOSoftware I want users to be able to navigate the mega dropdown menu. currently, the challenge is that when I hover over the dropdown it shows the dropdown menu but it disappears quickly when I try to select a menu.

A snippet of my scenario is included below:
https://codepen.io/mblaise0/pen/oNKbmOg

OK, I see it. There is no connection between the <a> tag area for "LOREM IPSUM" and the dropdown menu that it open. That means you can't move to the dropdown menu from the <a> tag. You need to make sure the mouse cursor in inside either of these two when moving over the menu. Use the browser developer tools to inspect the DOM.

is there a way to resolve this? @KIKOSoftware

The problem is, there’s “space” between the links that trigger the mega menu, and the mega menu itself. So in between moving your mouse from the trigger to the mega menu itself, your pointer travels through empty space, and therefore the mega menu closes. You need to not put margin/padding around your links.

thanks @MartinBean

You need to make the hovered element adjacent with the dropdown menu.
So when you pass your cursor one to another process won't be blocked.
Try this codes below.
.header {
  min-height: 70pt;
}

#alaid-header .logo h1 {
  font-size: 38px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#alaid-header .logo h1 a,
#alaid-header .logo h1 a:hover {
  color: #3c4133;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#alaid-header .logo img {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 78px;
}

*/ .navbar {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.navbar li {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #026a3f !important;
}

.navbar a,
.navbar a:focus {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 30px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: 0.3s;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar a i,
.navbar a:focus i {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.navbar .active,
.navbar .active:focus,
.navbar li:hover>a {
  color: #c57b0d !important;
}

.navbar a i {
  color: #c57b0d !important;
}


/* dropdown 2 */

.dropdown-menu {
  width: 980px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  /* z-index: 99; */
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  /* background-color: #fff; */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 5s ease;
}

.dropdown-hover:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 250;
}

.dropdown-hover>.dropdown-toggle:active {
  /*Without this, clicking will make it sticky*/
  pointer-events: none;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
  font-size: 13px !important;
  margin-left: -29px;
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<header id="alaid-header" class="d-flex align-items-stretch bg-white shadow header">
  <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="logo">
      <h1 class="text-light">
        <a href="index.php">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="w-100" />
        </a>
      </h1>
    </div>

    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar alaid-navbar align-items-stretch p-0 h-100">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link active" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item  dropdown-hover position-static">
          <a data-mdb-dropdown-init class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-mdb-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Lorem ipsum<i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i>
        </a>
          <!-- Dropdown menu -->
          <div class="dropdown-menu w-100 mt-0" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-top-left-radius: 0;border-top-right-radius: 0;">
            <div class="container mx-0">
              <div class="row my-4">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 mb-3 mb-lg-0">
                  <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <h6><strong>Lorem3</strong></h6>
                    <hr />
                    <a href="">lorem ipsum eer</a>
                    <a href="">lorem ipsum</a>
                    <a href="">lorem emsm</a>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 mb-3 mb-lg-0">
                  <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <h6><strong>Dogs</strong></h6>
                    <hr />
                    <a href="">Caucaian</a>
                    <a href="">Bull</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


thanks, @Oktay, this solves the issue
